# How to show the values from array, from child component to parent?

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I need to get the values from an array that it's in the child component and display that data in the parent component, how can I do that?

I was showing the data from the array only when the ‘save’ button was clicked but now I need to display the array by default.

**child.component.ts**

```
    tabs = [
    {
      name: 'Tab 1',
      placeholder: 'placeholder1',
      formControlName: 'inputValue',
      value: '',
    },
    {
      name: 'Tab 2',
      placeholder: 'placeholder2',
      formControlName: 'inputValue',
      value: '',
    },
  ];
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-components-demo-n3raag?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more on the issue. As far as communication b/w various components is concern, there are multiple ways to achieve it in Angular. e.g. 1. Via Event bindings 2. Via services. I would suggest that the best approach to communicate among components is using the services.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement `OnInit` in your child component in your case.

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit
```

Then call your `submit()` method within your `OnInit` implementation

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.submit();
}
```

So when the child gets initialized, it emmits the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use output method in child component ,

```
@Output() selectedtabs = new EventEmitter<tabs[]>();

ngOnInit(): {
submit(tab:tabs){
  this.selectedtabs.emit(tab);
}

here tabs is the interface , 
// on parent component 

//parent html 
 <component-name  (selectedtabs)="selecttabs($event)"></component-name>

//parent ts file

ngOnInit(): {
selecttab(tab: tabs) {
    this.selectedtab = tab;
  }
```